# Ability to download file(pdf) in a report in jasperserver

Tags: jasperserver

I have a requirement where i have to list out pdf files which are in my file system, these information(file name, file path) are saved in the database. Now in a report i want to display all those pdf (as hyperlink/button or any ) and if i click on the report name it should be downloaded. How can i do this? is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it is possible to link directly to an archived report using a fileview statement. If you have run and stored a copy of the report you can reference it to open directly using a statement like this for authenticated users:

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/fileview/fileview/somepath/createdname.pdf?
```

Now the second piece about displaying all existing reports for the user in a report would require you to create an additional connection to the jasperdb created on install and writing a query against the resource table to view all reports within this format.

Comment: I created file in "C:/reports/myreport.pdf", but when i give this url "`http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/fileview/fileview/C:/reports/myreport.pdf`" am getting below error on the display. **Details: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: jsexception.could.not.find.content.resource.with.uri**

Comment: is there any configuration that i need to do?

Comment: Hi Shri - The configuration path ("somepath/createdname.pdf?" needs to be within the JasperServer directory - like "Reports/Archive/reportname.pdf" instead of the directory on your local machine. If you navigate to the report source itself through the repository and open it, you can see in the url window the correct path.

Comment: You're welcome - hope that helped!

Comment: Yes, it really helped me, :) tnx.